# Scroll outside or below content in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I would like to be able to scroll further down in Eclipse, below the last line of content in the file.
A lot of editors/IDEs support this, IntelliJ and TextPad, for instance. Vim if enabled.
It's a bit annoying having to put 20 empty lines in the bottom of every file in order for the code I'm writing to appear in the middle of the screen.

Any suggestions?

I've only found a few hits on Google, that are old. And I'm not sure what this is named, so if you have a word for it please tell, as it will help me in my search.

**As it seems it's not possible at the moment, I would like suggestions on how to best overcome this issue.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation, and there is a bug opened for this - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362540. You can add your thoughts to the bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I feel this is a bit aside from what I'm meaning. The bug you are linking to has more to do with how it doesn't scroll properly down when typing, so you end up typing with more content below.

Comment: A bug can sometimes be broader in scope. The mentioned bug also covers your problem see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362540#c4 point (a).